# Visual Studio Left aligns line on hitting enter

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I hit enter, Visual studio left aligns the line the cursor was on every time. I am forced to do Ctrl+K Ctrl+D to restore formatting. Not sure what I am missing. What could be the reason? Has anyone encountered this in the past?

Comment: Check your formatting settings (None, vs Block, vs Smart). Also try resetitng your settings and seeing if it repros.

Comment: It is set to Smart. I tried the others too.

Comment: How can I reset the settings?

Comment: Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) installed? By default it does not indent children of `html`, `body`, `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot`. If you, as I, believe that children of `body` should be indented, go to `ReSharper|Options` and `Code Editing|HTML|Formatting Style|Do not indent children of` and remove "body" from the setting.

[image: ReSharper HTML formatting style]

Comment: Why the downvote, both on OP and on my answer? It's an answer to the question? Not nice to downvote without comment ...